# Django not applying css files or displaying image

Tags: python, css, django

I am figuring out how to use django, and this is my first project (other than the tutorial). I am trying to apply some css to my html using static files, but I see no change in the html. I tried displaying an image just to see if there was something wrong with my css, but that didn't work either. When I run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it is collecting my files so I know that it can find them. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the head of my html file:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mainpage/mainpage.css' %}">
</head>
```

And here is where I try to load the image:

```
<img src="{% static 'mainpage/example.jpg' %}" alt="Example Image">
```

The css file (this is just the mainpage one, but the others are similar):

```
h1 {
color: green;
}
li a {
color: green;
}
header {
  background-color: black;
}
```

And my file structure:

```
abstract
|
|---mainpage
|   |
|   |--- static
|   |          |
|   |          |---mainpage
|   |          |          |
|   |          |          |---mainpage.css
|   |          |          |
|   |          |          |---example.jpg
```

Again, it can find the files, so that is not the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the webserver log say about the browser's requests to load those files?   Were they served successfully (i.e. status result code was 200), or was there a problem (i.e. status result code was 404)?

Comment: All I see is `[13/Jul/2018 17:17:29] "GET /mainpage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 799`. Am I supposed to see it load the static files?

Comment: The browser might be caching the css files, in which case it would not request those, but it should at least be requesting the image.

Comment: Just though I should confirm that it does in fact show that it loads the css files, as well as the image. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

`{% load static %}` in your template before you try to load static files.

Comment: I did, sorry should have put that in: `{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mainpage/mainpage.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was pretty stupid, but I change the location of base.html, but in my text editor I was still "editing" the one at the old location, so naturally none of my changes were appearing. Sorry to trouble you with a stupid mistake. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!